# Different profiling modes for different cores using perf

Tags: performance, performancecounter

I have the following questions regarding perf.

a) Is it possible that I run different profiling modes on different cores simultaneously. e.g. Core 0 with event based sampling (sampling every N events) and Core 1 with free running counter based sampling?

b) In case a) is not possible. Then is it possible to get a snapshot of the PMU counters on the other cores (Core 1) for every sample (overflow at N events) on Core 0?

P.S: The platform is a RPi 3b+ based on the Arm Cortex A53

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to operate different profiling modes on different cores of the CPU simultaneously.

`perf` also has a processor-wide mode wherein all threads running on the designated processors are monitored. Counts and samples are thus aggregated per CPU/core.

```
       -C, --cpu=
           Count only on the list of CPUs provided. Multiple CPUs can be
           provided as a comma-separated list with no space: 0,1. Ranges of
           CPUs are specified with -: 0-2. In per-thread mode, this option
           is ignored. The -a option is still necessary to activate
           system-wide monitoring. Default is to count on all CPUs.
```

Running both the free-running counter as well as the sampling mechanism of `perf` simultaneously, is possible on different cores of the CPU like below -

eg. for cpu 0:

`perf stat --cpu 0 -B dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null count=1000000`

and for cpu 1:

`perf record --cpu 1 sleep 20`